# javascript copy input from textbot to drop down

Tags: javascript, html, validation

here is the code, i have a code that copy's the value of an input textbox to another textbox on another page, now i want to copy the textbox value down to drop down and list them, is there a way i can do it, hope someone can help me, thanks a lot

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function data_copy()
{

if(document.form1.copy[0].checked){
document.form1.pass1Name.value=document.form1.passName1.value;
document.form1.pass2Name.value=document.form1.passName2.value;
document.form1.pass3Name.value=document.form1.passName3.value;
document.form1.pass4Name.value=document.form1.passName4.value;
document.form1.pass5Name.value=document.form1.passName5.value;
document.form1.pass12Name.value=document.form1.passName1.value;
document.form1.pass13Name.value=document.form1.passName2.value;
document.form1.pass14Name.value=document.form1.passName3.value;
document.form1.pass15Name.value=document.form1.passName4.value;
document.form1.pass16Name.value=document.form1.passName5.value;



}else{
document.form1.pass1Name.value="";
document.form1.pass2Name.value="";
document.form1.pass3Name.value="";
document.form1.pass4Name.value="";
document.form1.pass5Name.value="";


}

}

</script>
```

i want to copy the value of the textboxes inside a drop down, like the code below, please help me, what codes need to be added, thanks

```
<select name="health">
<option value="">value of pass1Name</option>
<option value="">value of pass1Name</option>
<option value="">value of pass1Name</option>
<option value="">value of pass1Name</option>
<option value="">value of pass1Name</option>
</select>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: can you post the code where you call the data_copy function

Comment: yes just a simple, radio button..you can find it below, thanks for helping                                                                                                                                 <div style="color:#fff;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:0px;">Yes <input type=radio class=radio name=copy value=yes onClick="data_copy()"> No <input type=radio class=radio name=copy value=no onClick="data_copy()"></div>

Answer (score 0):

you can append option to select like this.
So, get value from text box and set it as select value,

```
var option = new Option(value, text);
$('#health').append($(option));
```

You can also use this:

```
$('#health').append('<option val="1">One</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="example-select"></select>

var select = document.getElementById("example-select");
var value = document.form1.passName1.value;
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
```

same way you can add more values from passName2, passName3 etc.

Comment: thank you i will try this one and inform you if it works, thanks

Comment: is this correct <script type="text/javascript">
var select = document.getElementById("health");
var value = document.form1.passName1.value;
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);

</script>

Comment: sir when i go back and forth on the pages, the content are duplicating, they will be added twice, is there a way i can get rid of it?

Comment: var value = document.form1.passName1.value;
    if (value != "") 
    {
        var select = document.getElementById("example-select");
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        var flag = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
        {
          if(select[i].value == value)
          {   
              flag = 1;
          }
        }
        if(flag == 0)
        {
          option.text = value;
          select.add(option,select.option);
          select.selectedIndex = select.options.length - 1;
        }
    }